# How to limit FTP connection time

Tags: php, ftp, timeout

I have FTP server with IP public, let say: 192.0.0.12. But in some area with different  network, connection to this IP is not applicable. In this case, we can connect to the FTP through another IP, let say: 171.0.0.13.

So I have write script in PHP to connect to the FTP server and download the files by using `ftp_connect()`. To avoid the long respond, I set the time limit to 5 seconds using `set_time_limit()`. This is the script:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
function ftp_konek($ftp_server){
    set_time_limit(5);
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
    return $conn_id;
}
if(ftp_konek($ftp_server)){
    /*download the file*/
}else{
    $ftp_server = "171.0.0.13";
    $change_ip = ftp_konek($ftp_server);
    if($change_ip){
       /*download the file*/
    }else{
       echo "Failed!";
    }
}
?>
```

The public IP and username+password are stored in the `config.php`. The idea is:

1. Connect to FTP server using the first IP.
2. If succeed in 5 seconds, download the file.
3. Else if not succeed, change the FTP server IP and connect.
4. If connection succeed, download the file

The problem is, I got warning:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 5 seconds exceeded

And the operation stopped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, have paid more attention to the issue!

The maximum execution time of your script is 5 seconds, which is extremely low. The default timeout for `ftp_connect` is 90 seconds, so obviously some issues.

Change

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
```

To

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 2);
```

And it will probably work. I would also look to set the maximum execution time much higher. If you put this at the start of your script:

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

Then you could use a more reasonable timeout

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp_connect` function has `$timeout` parameter.

Set that instead of hacking this by limiting PHP execution time.

```
ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_time_limit` sets the global time limit **for the entire script,** not just for `ftp_connect`. `ftp_connect` has its own 3rd parameter `$timeout`:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21, 5);
```